# Как узнать что БД скопирована на устройство?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

При первой инициализации объекта **dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper** вылезает ошибка **java.lang.NullPointerException**, а при повторном вызове, ошибки нет.

```
public DBHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    System.out.print(context.getFilesDir().getPath());
    DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + DB_NAME;
    this.mycontext = context;
    boolean dbExists = checkdatabase();
    if (dbExists)
        opendatabase();
    else
        createdatabase();
    //dbIsReady = true;
}
```

**createdatabase() opendatabase() opendatabase()** описывать не буду, т.к. названия говорящие
Есть ли адекватный способ проверить существует ли база данных на устройстве или как-то *приостановить основной поток*, пока база данных копируется на устройство

просто я сделал корявый, с переменной **boolean** в классе dbHelper, которая становится **true** в конце конструктора (который копирует бд на устройство, если её нет), и в главном потоке

```
...
do {} while(db.isDbReady());
...
```

БД своя, сделанная на компьютере.
Добавил её в assets проекта и мне надо, чтобы бд копировалась в устройство, к примеру 2гис, по городам и в каждом городе БД заведений, транспорта, и т.д.
Вот я собираюсь сделать БД кафе в городе, и поэтому делаю бд на компьютере, чтобы не париться с **ContentValues**

*LogCat*

```
04-04 12:21:23.670 14687-14687/ru.vladdev.andrmenu E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: ru.vladdev.andrmenu, PID: 14687
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.vladdev.andrmenu/ru.vladdev.andrmenu.CafeMenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:168)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5589)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
 at ru.vladdev.andrmenu.CafeMenuActivity.onCreate(CafeMenuActivity.java:32)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5993)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:168) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5589) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

Comment: А где именно NullPointerException возникает? Без этого и вывода в логи вместо помощи вы получите лишь гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Как минимум можно проверить существует ли сама БД в файловой системе, а именно проверить существование файла БД, а так я согласен с Юрием, нужно больше конкретики, хоть логи дайте

Comment: База создается через запрос ```CREATE TABLE```, или вы уже готовую копируете откуда то? Если первое, то нет необходимости проверять наличие БД, т.к. при правильно реализованном наследнике ```SQLiteOpenHelper ```, в частности методов ```onCreate``` и ```onUpgrade```, при отсутствие БД они вызовутся автоматически

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Посмотреть и скопировать бд можно через Android Device Monitor.

Обрати внимание на методы SQLiteOpenHelper

```
onCreate () - здесь создаешь БД
onUpgrade () - здесь обновляешь БД для след релиза
```